# After let(:user) { create(:user) } # => RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a test case:

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { create(:user) } # FactoryGirl
  it { User.count == 1 }  
end
```

And setup:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

Why it is not working?
How to use let and got a really persisted records?

Comment: is `it { User.count == 1 }` your actual test? Because there's no assertion in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` calls are lazy-evaluated, they aren't run unless the specific method is called:

```
describe User do
  subject { user }
  let(:user) { create(:user) } # FactoryGirl
  it { … }  
end
```

Alternatively, use `let!` for preconditions which are always evaluated:

```
describe User do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) } # FactoryGirl
  it { … }  
end
```